# watch of *v1.Pod ended with: too old resource version

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I updated my EKS from 1.16 to 1.17. All of sudden I started getting this error:

```
pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20180806134042-1f13a808da65/tools/cache/reflector.go:99: watch of *v1.Pod ended with: too old resource version
```

Checked on git and people were saying that's not an error but my question is how to stop getting these messages? I was not getting this message when I was having EKS 1.16?

[Source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22024#issuecomment-195509864).

Comment: In which pod are you getting these messages ?

Comment: /var/log/containers/aws-alb-ingress-controller and /var/log/containers/aws-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to expand it.

In short, there is nothing to worry about when encountering these messages. They mean that there are newer version(s) of the watched resource after the time the client API last acquired a list within that watch window. In other words: a watch against the Kubernetes API is timing out, and it is being restarted, which is a intended behavior.

You can also see that being mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22024#issuecomment-591814814):

> this is perfectly expected, no worries. The messages are several hours
> apart.
>
> When nothing happens in your cluster, the watches established by the
> Kubernetes client don't get a chance to get refreshed naturally, and
> eventually time out. These messages simply indicate that these watches
> are being re-created.

and [here](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/2730#issuecomment-524342055):

> these are nothing to worry about. This is a known occurrence in
> Kubernetes and is not an issue [0]. The API server ends watch requests
> when they are very old. The operator uses a client-go informer, which
> takes care of automatically re-listing the resource and then
> restarting the watch from the latest resource version.

So answering your question:

> my question is how to stop getting these messages

Simply, you don't [because](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22024):

> This is working as expected and is not going to be fixed.

Comment: I accepted this as an answer but I updated the EKS and now not getting this warnings